# Drawing simple Triangle with OpenGLES in Android Studio using only C++ code and JNI

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm learning using OpenGL ES with the JNI (Java Native Interface). I'm currently trying to draw a simple Triangle with NDK installed in Android Studio through this example : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-gl2.

I haven't learnt java before, so I want to write all the code in C++ and call it through the JNI. However, there's still some java code in the GL2JNIView.java of this example, which makes me confused. Could someone guide me how to draw this Triangle with only C++ code and call those functions through JNI please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sample, hello-gl2, there is no java code draws a triangle. The sample project is exactly what you are looking for. In the sample, Java only calls C++ code(which actually draws a triangle) through JNI.

If you really don't like to use java at all, there is an option that you can use a **[native-activity](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na.html)**. However, I recommend to mix Java & c++ since the android native environment is limited to use all android features that you might need. I, for example, use c++ most in android development although very barely, I need to use android api which is only supported in JAVA.

If I used the native-activity, there wouldn't be no option to use them I needed

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 

About the hello-gl2 sample, it use java code to create EGL Context, Surface and others thing. But I decide to have a look into the java thanks to your recommendation.

Btw, the native-activity is exactly what i want from the beginning but there's still 1 more thing missing in that project.There's no JNI in the native-activity project yet so I still couldn't know how to call the native code from JNI, could you help me out pls?

Comment: @ToanTran The purpose of native-activity is not to use JNI. The EGL Context is not what you need to care. Just use the EGL Context they made or change small code of that if needed. If you use a native-activity, AFAIK, you can't call any JAVA method which means you can't use JNI.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. By the way, I still have a question. If the purpose of native-activity is not to use JNI then how to display the Triangle to the screen in Android Studio? The native-activity doesn't show how to do that, all I got when I run the App is a blank dark screen.

Comment: @ToanTran I found an example of Native-Activity with OpenGL es 2.0 https://github.com/kapsy/original-native/blob/master/jni/original_native.cpp but again, I don't recommend the native activity because I was doing the same thing as a c++ lover but I had to mix them c++& Java to take more advantages of Android features

Comment: Your answers helped me alot, thank you. I will have a look at this native activity but I will take your advice and learn some Java basics. Thank you again :)